# Unpacked extension not loaded on browser startup

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

For some reason my unpacked extension stopped being loaded when browser starts, I have to manually open extensions tabs and load unpacked extension.

If I rename extension's folder, Edge assigns a new ID to it and than it automatically gets loaded on startup. It's like original ID got banned or something?

Anyone know why this happening and how can I "unban" original ID? (without removing profile)

P.S.
not certain if this question is more suitable for `superuser` or `stackoverlow`

Comment: Does the same problem exist in other browsers? Or is there any error message on the extension page? I'm not sure how the problem occurred, if I can provide steps to reproduce the problem, it will help solve the problem.

Comment: No, Chrome, Chromium and Edge Dev don't have this issue. All of them generate the same ID for the extension and load it on startup. I've tried it on the the same Edge version on another computer (virtual) and it worked there too.

Comment: Based on the results you described, I think there may be some problems in your current environment, but I am not sure what you have modified. You can try to clear the cache and reset the settings in Edge. If this still does not work, I think you may need to reinstall ms Edge.